# Where to keep PGP private key file and when to download in springboot application. I am considering to keep file in Azure blob storage

Tags: java, spring-boot, architecture, azure-blob-storage, pgp

I have a spring-boot application that listens to a consumer azure topic and downloads a PGP encrypted file whenever there is a message in the topic. After downloading the encrypted file, I need to decrypt the file using a private key file. Should I keep the private key file in azure blob storage and download it at the start of the application? Looking for suggestions.

Comment: You can store it as key in Azure Key Vault: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/keys/about-keys.

Comment: @MarkusMeyer Azure key vault does not support .asc files.

Comment: You can at the content as text into the key